# java - Non-static method 'getLogger' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to create a simple logging application in Java using `log4j2`.

This is how it looks:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


    public class Main {

       private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String message = "Hello there!";
            System.out.println(message);
            logger.info(message);

        }
    }
```

There is an error on `getLogger`
claiming:

```
 Non-static method 'getLogger' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I've looked into various threads on this forum but none of them seemed to work. They seemed to declare the logger the same way as I did above.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the `import` statements to your code.

Comment: You want to `getLogMananger()` first to get an instance. `getLogger` is not static. Than the paramter must be a `String`. So I guess you are not using the correct class. `Logger` of `log4j` should be what you want (accepting a `class` parameter)

Comment: You should use `Logger.getLogger(Main.class);`

Comment: @AleksandarDimitrov It doesn't seem to recognize `.getLogger` method

Comment: You are not using log4j2, you are using "java.util.logging"

Comment: Try `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Class.class)`?

Comment: I fixed this by removing my import and replacing it with 
`import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

`import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `log4j2` then you imported the wrong `LogManager` and `Logger`. You should have this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

You should take a look to the documentation : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html

### EDIT: Maven

According to the documentation [Using Log4j in your Apache Maven build](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html), you should have the following dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Okay it seems to work now. It's strange when I press ALT+Enter on the code, it doesn't inform me to import the correct class.

Comment: Where do I download the jar files for the API?

Comment: You should consider using Maven or Gradle for dependency management. But you can also download the libs here : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Comment: Because apparently, I imported the jar to my classpath and it still says  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterVisitable`

Comment: I did use Maven for importing dependency but it seems it gives the error above

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have imported the wrong Logger, it should be as bellow

```js
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

Here is the working example

```js
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String message = "Hello there!";
    System.out.println(message);
    logger.info(message);

  }


}
```

And if you are using the wrong maven dependency, Do use the bellow one

```html
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I still get an error after importing the correct one `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterVisitable`